# Fixes for problems with SubSonic 3's TestRepository

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, subsonic-active-record

I've been trying to use SubSonic 3.0's test repository support for unit testing but encountered a few issues, so I thought I document them, and the fixes I've come up with:

### Auto-Increment Columns Don't Work

Obviously with no DB, auto-increment columns don't work automatically, but if like me you're using simple ints or longs for all identity columns, this fix works well:

(This is a copy from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508706/subsonic-3-active-record-testrepository-identity-column-not-icremented/2452170#2452170), included for completeness)

In ActiveRecord.tt:

1: In the top of the function public void Add(IDataProvider provider){

```
        public void Add(IDataProvider provider){

<#if(tbl.PK.SysType=="long" || tbl.PK.SysType=="int") {#>
            if (TestMode)
            {
                this.<#=tbl.PK.CleanName#>=++next_test_autoid;
            }

<#}#>
```

2: Under the line public bool TestMode = false, add:

```
        public bool TestMode = false;
<#if(tbl.PK.SysType=="long" || tbl.PK.SysType=="int") {#>
        private static <#=tbl.PK.SysType#> next_test_autoid = 0;
<#}#>
```

### Object Equality Comparison is Broken

Using the default ActiveRecord template, object equality doesn't work. So removing items from the DB doesn't work since the List<>.Remove() used in the TestRepository fails to match the item being removed.  This can be fixed in the tt templates with the following: (ie: replacing "==" with "Equals()")

In ActiveRecord.tt:

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj){
        if(obj.GetType()==typeof(<#=tbl.ClassName#>)){
            <#=tbl.ClassName#> compare=(<#=tbl.ClassName#>)obj;
            return compare.KeyValue().Equals(this.KeyValue());
        }else{
            return base.Equals(obj);
        }
    }
```

### DeleteMany is Not Implemented in the Test Repository

Operations like this `records.Delete(x => x.whatever == whatever)` fail against the test repo because DeleteMany is not implemented.  Fixing this requires getting the source and building yourself, but here's an implementation that seems to work:

In TestRepository.cs:

```
    public int DeleteMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        foreach (var x in _items.AsQueryable().Where(expression).ToList())
        {
            _items.Remove(x);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for this - but the best thing to do is to tell us about your issues :). StackOverflow is more for answering questions - I might suggest heading over to Github and checking the latest source (we've fixed a number of these). If you see that some things can be fixed - patches are very welcome.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I actually checked the latest github version before posting this and couldn't see fixes for any of these issues. Also, the auto-increment thing, I wouldn't think you'd actually want that in the standard templates (since I'm not sure it works in all cases).  The other issues I'll submit a patch for today.

Answer (score 0):

As to point 2, this is still broken if the record is not yet saved, as it is comparing on KeyValue(). To ensure that non-saved records also have true equality, we must also test if the record IsNew, and if so, determine another equality strategy

Comment: Too true, speaking as one just bitten! Remove() won't work on unsaved records because they don't have an id to compare equal. Probably should fall back to reference equality if id==0/IsNew().